# Display mysql in a html table with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

i'm learning how to use node.js with mysql. I've tried to find some good documentation but in vain. i'm at the point where I can get my mysql data displayed in my browser but I want to handle it through my index.html and a css file at some point.

This is my app.js:

```
// moduels
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('bodyParser')

// 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// connect to database
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "1234",
    database: "BathBombs_DB"
});

// routes
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    console.log('GET request received at /') 
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else{
            response.send(result)
        }

    });
});

// listen for trafic and display on localhost:9000
app.listen(9000, function () {
    console.log('Connected to port 9000');
});
```

My index.html site looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/" method="POST">
            <table type="text" name="firstname" ></table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an ajax call to get a result from the server and bind with HTML content using javascript as below :

HTML template

```
 <table id="tableData" class="table table-fixed">
<thead>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbody" >
</tbody>
```

Here is the script to make an ajax call

```
$(document).ready(() => {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9000/list", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.rows.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.rows.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var firstname = '';
                var lastname = '';
                var gender = '';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].firstname +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].lastname +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].gender+'</td>';                
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#tableData .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})
```

Comment: hey i can't seem to get it to display anything and i don't get any errors

Comment: Did you include the script file with priya's answer into your html file? (<script src="yourpath.js"></script>)
Also, to display your data, you don't need a form. Having the table in the form may cause difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply display like this inside `<table>` Tag :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>firstname</th>
          </tr>
          <% if(result.length){ 
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=result.firstname%></td>
          </tr>
           <% }
          }else{ %>
          <tr>
            <td>No user</td>
          </tr>
        <% } %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need "**ship/send**" your "index.html" file to browser. 
For that you need to define an API end point like below (which will send the index.html to the browser).

```
/* GET home page. */
app.get('/', getMainPage);

function getMainPage(req, res) {

  console.debug('Route for mainViewpage: ' + __dirname );
  console.log(process.env);
  var mainViewFile = __dirname + '/../public/views/index.html'; // Replace  this with path to your index.html file
  console.log('mainView log' , mainViewFile);
  fs.readFile(mainViewFile, function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
  });
}
```

Once this is done, follow the approach given by @priya tarun in prvious answer.

Note: You also need to include Jquery in your html file. Your "index.html" would look something like this. I havent tested fully, you can do that part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--Inlcudes JQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>

    <form action="/" method="POST">
            <table type="text" name="firstname" ></table>
    </form>

</body>

$(document).ready(() => {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9000/getCustomerData", 
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        if(response.rows.length > 0){
            for(let index = 0; index < response.rows.length; index++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr>");
                var cols = "";
                var firstname = '';
                var lastname = '';
                var gender = '';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].firstname +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].lastname +'</td>';
                cols += '<td> '+ response.rows[index].gender+'</td>';                
                newRow.append(cols);
                $("#tableData .tbody").append(newRow);
            }  

        }
    }
})
})
</html>
```

Note: **Rename your API end point to get customer data as "/getCustomerData" instead of just "/" .
Use the API end point "/" to serve your "index.html" to the client/browser.**

Add comments in case you have any confusion on this

Comment: Note that I have slightly modified @priya tarun's answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use a query builder like Knex JS. It provides better experience and is easier to use. I am sure following code will make sense to you:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const http = require('http');

const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});

const record = await knex.select('title', 'author', 'year').from('books');
const displayBody = record.map(single => {
   return `<tr>
             <td>${single.title}</td>
             <td>${single.author}</td>
             <td>${single.year}</td>
           </tr>`;
})

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    response.write('<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>');
    response.write(displayBody);
    response.write('</tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>');
    response.end();
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

In the above code we are getting the data from `books` table to display or return that.

Answer (score 0):

This you can handle using plain javascript, please find below code snippet, I have used hardcode data, but you can handle with API response as on success you can trigger GenerateTable() to render in HTML:

```js
function GenerateTable() {
        //Build an array containing Customer records.
        var customers = new Array();
        customers.push(["Customer Id", "Name", "Country"]);
        customers.push([1, "John Hammond", "United      States"]);
        customers.push([2, "Mudassar Khan", "India"]);
        customers.push([3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France"]);
        customers.push([4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia"]);

        //Create a HTML Table element.
        var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
        table.border = "1";
 
        //Get the count of columns.
        var columnCount = customers[0].length;
 
        //Add the header row.
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
            var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = customers[0][i];
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
        }
 
        //Add the data rows.
        for (var i = 1; i < customers.length; i++) {
            row = table.insertRow(-1);
            for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = customers[i][j];
            }
        }
 
        var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
        dvTable.innerHTML = "";
        dvTable.appendChild(table);
    }

function handleApiResponse() {
//$.ajax({
//                type: "GET",               
//                url: URL,               
//                dataType: "jsonp",
//                error: function (response) {           
//                        alert('Error: There was a problem //processing your request, please refresh the browser and //try again');
//                },
//                success: function (response) {
//                GenerateTable(response)
//               }
//        });
GenerateTable()
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Generate Table" onclick="handleApiResponse()" />
<hr />
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```