# How to decode a BLOB object from mysql DB to png image using node js and handlerbars to show in a catalog

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, blob

i Have some trouble trying to get this image from the DB, this BLOB file are PNG.

[image: BLOB's in the DB]

I'm using this js code to read the DB BLOB but how can i use it to render in my html

```
 router.get('/productos/ofertas',async(req,res) => {
     const ofer = await pool.query('SELECT art_id,clave,claveAlterna,descripcion,precio1,caracteristicas from articulo where  art_id between 10 and 25');
     const img = await pool.query('SELECT imagen FROM imagen where img_id =20'); 
     console.log(img[0])
     res.render('links/ofertas', {ofer,img});
 });
```

and i get this in my console

[image: CONSOLE LOG RESPONSE]

I render this with handlerbars like this

```
<div class="container p-3">
        <div class="row">
       {{#each ofer}}
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          {{#each img}}
  <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="data:image/png;base64,{{imagen}}">  I WANT TO LOAD THE IMAGES HERE FOR EACH ITEM
          {{/each}}
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{clave}}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{descripcion}}</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{claveAlterna}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{caracteristicas}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-body">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
            {{else}}
            <div class="col-md4 mx-auto">
                <div class="card card-body text-center">   
                    <p>NO HAY OFERTAS POR AHORA, REVISA NUESTROS PRODUCTOS!</p>
                    <a href="/links/productos">Productos!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
       {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
<footer class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="d-block mb-2" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Product</title><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"/><path d="M14.31 8l5.74 9.94M9.69 8h11.48M7.38 12l5.74-9.94M9.69 16L3.95 6.06M14.31 16H2.83m13.79-4l-5.74 9.94"/></svg>
      <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2020</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the img src

Comment: Don't embed your images. Use `<img src="yourserver/api/image/{{someid}}">` and write some code in your server that can service that URL pattern, so that your index file stays small, and the browser can cache images, both contributing to your server being far more responsive, and your costs (cpu cycles and bandwidth) stay low.

Comment: your problem is that you receive rows from await pool.query  and you send to the html that rows. so you should start by reding up on how to display rows. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992092/display-mysql-in-a-html-table-with-node-js

Comment: I have to pile on here. Storing images in BLOBs is a *really bad* idea. Why? In a busy web app, the database server is the scarcest resource. If you burden it with serving images, things will slow down just when you start to be successful. Serve your images from a file system. Store the path to each image file in your table.

Comment: What do you see in the browser with View Source...? It's hard to tell from your question if your image blobs are stored binary or base64 encoded. If they're binary, you must encode them to base64 to put them into data: urls.  There's nothing wrong with doing that, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 's comment notwithstanding. But you have to encode the image correctly.

Comment: except there is, because it makes for *huge* .html files that your server constantly has to regenerate, that can't be cached despite the vast bulk of the data _not changing_ on page (re)loads. Naturally, decode correctly, but even more importantly: don't do this. This is not a good approach and learning that is important.