# How to put data from sql into a table in html using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I have DATA stored in mysql.
And I want to display it in a table in HTML.
I am currently using NODE.JS AND EXPRESS.
How can I save the DATA that comes in and put it into a table in HTML.
I was trying to find a way to save this DATA,
And use a MAP loop inside a script tag in HTML,
But I could not send the DATA to HTML .

app.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const SQL = require('sql-template-strings')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const Joi = require('joi');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))


// connect to MySQL
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass123',
    database: 'carStorege'
})

con.connect((err)=> {
    if(err) throw err;
    else console.log('connect to DB !')
})

// seva data from database
con.query("SELECT * from Cars", (err, result, fields) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else {
         //save the data
        const data = result
    }
})
// express

    // url to see all the car in table

    app.get('/all', (req, res) => {
        con.query("SELECT * from Cars", (err, result, fields) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            else {
                res.sendFile(__dirname+'/allCars.html')
            }
        })

    })


app.listen(port, () => console.log('srever is live'))
```

*and this is the HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <tr>
        <th>Car manufacturer</th>
        <th>Car model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Yaer</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Door number</th>
    </tr>
    // here the data shuld be
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display mysql in a html table with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992092/display-mysql-in-a-html-table-with-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be done in front-end javascript. The JS on your webpage (connected to the HTML) needs to request the data from your Node server, then `doSomething` with it. It will likely be in an array, so you can just loop through the array, create a new HTML row with the data in it, and append that to the correct spot in your table. Something like:

```
fetch('http://yourWebSite.com/api/all')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let table = document.querySelector('#tableId')
        data.forEach(row => {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th').innerText(row.item1))
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th').innerText(row.item2))
            tr.appendChild(document.createElement('th').innerText(row.item3))
            table.appendChild(tr)
        })
});
```

This is where frameworks come in handy, since a library like React, Vue, or Angular have rendering strategies that are designed to handle this.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot